# Android RecyclerView Vertical Scroll Offset Bug

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have a vertical RecyclerView and an image behind it. I want to change the alpha of the image while the user scrolls. The further down the user scrolls, the higher the alpha gets creating an appearance effect.

My solution is based on adding a `OnScrollListener` and `computeVerticalScrollOffset`. Below is my code:

```
RecyclerView.OnScrollListener scrollListener = new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
            super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
        }

        @Override
        public void onScrolled(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
            int scrollY = recyclerView.computeVerticalScrollOffset();
            float alpha = Math.max(0f, Math.min(scrollY / 1000f, 1f));
            image.setAlpha(alpha);
            Log.d("zzz", "scroll measuredHeight="+recyclerView.getMeasuredHeight() +", scrollY="+scrollY+", alpha="+alpha);
        }
    };
```

However, I noticed that when user scrolls down, the `scrollY` does not increment consistently. At one point its value decreases even though the user is scrolling further. I also noticed that if I add a vertical thumb, I can see it jump back high when scrolling. This to me indicates that perhaps the height of the recyclerView is changing which is causing this. But despite that, I still want a solution that handles that. Below is the log showing the different values:

```
2023-03-09 08:59:29.325 30661-30661/com.superpowered.backtrackit D/zzz: scroll measuredHeight=1869, scrollY=440, alpha=0.44
2023-03-09 08:59:29.342 30661-30661/com.superpowered.backtrackit D/zzz: scroll measuredHeight=1869, scrollY=448, alpha=0.448
2023-03-09 08:59:29.359 30661-30661/com.superpowered.backtrackit D/zzz: scroll measuredHeight=1869, scrollY=454, alpha=0.454
2023-03-09 08:59:29.375 30661-30661/com.superpowered.backtrackit D/zzz: scroll measuredHeight=1869, scrollY=461, alpha=0.461
2023-03-09 08:59:29.392 30661-30661/com.superpowered.backtrackit D/zzz: scroll measuredHeight=1869, scrollY=467, alpha=0.467
2023-03-09 08:59:29.409 30661-30661/com.superpowered.backtrackit D/zzz: scroll measuredHeight=1869, scrollY=471, alpha=0.471
2023-03-09 08:59:29.425 30661-30661/com.superpowered.backtrackit D/zzz: scroll measuredHeight=1869, scrollY=477, alpha=0.477
2023-03-09 08:59:29.442 30661-30661/com.superpowered.backtrackit D/zzz: scroll measuredHeight=1869, scrollY=482, alpha=0.482
2023-03-09 08:59:29.461 30661-30661/com.superpowered.backtrackit D/zzz: scroll measuredHeight=1869, scrollY=487, alpha=0.487
2023-03-09 08:59:29.476 30661-30661/com.superpowered.backtrackit D/zzz: scroll measuredHeight=1869, scrollY=492, alpha=0.492
2023-03-09 08:59:29.494 30661-30661/com.superpowered.backtrackit D/zzz: scroll measuredHeight=1869, scrollY=496, alpha=0.496
2023-03-09 08:59:29.509 30661-30661/com.superpowered.backtrackit D/zzz: scroll measuredHeight=1869, scrollY=501, alpha=0.501
2023-03-09 08:59:29.526 30661-30661/com.superpowered.backtrackit D/zzz: scroll measuredHeight=1869, scrollY=506, alpha=0.506
2023-03-09 08:59:29.542 30661-30661/com.superpowered.backtrackit D/zzz: scroll measuredHeight=1869, scrollY=512, alpha=0.512
2023-03-09 08:59:29.561 30661-30661/com.superpowered.backtrackit D/zzz: scroll measuredHeight=1869, scrollY=520, alpha=0.52
2023-03-09 08:59:29.575 30661-30661/com.superpowered.backtrackit D/zzz: scroll measuredHeight=1869, scrollY=527, alpha=0.527
2023-03-09 08:59:29.592 30661-30661/com.superpowered.backtrackit D/zzz: scroll measuredHeight=1869, scrollY=534, alpha=0.534
2023-03-09 08:59:29.611 30661-30661/com.superpowered.backtrackit D/zzz: scroll measuredHeight=1869, scrollY=541, alpha=0.541
2023-03-09 08:59:29.626 30661-30661/com.superpowered.backtrackit D/zzz: scroll measuredHeight=1869, scrollY=546, alpha=0.546
2023-03-09 08:59:29.642 30661-30661/com.superpowered.backtrackit D/zzz: scroll measuredHeight=1869, scrollY=551, alpha=0.551
2023-03-09 08:59:29.659 30661-30661/com.superpowered.backtrackit D/zzz: scroll measuredHeight=1869, scrollY=556, alpha=0.556
2023-03-09 08:59:29.676 30661-30661/com.superpowered.backtrackit D/zzz: scroll measuredHeight=1869, scrollY=562, alpha=0.562
2023-03-09 08:59:29.692 30661-30661/com.superpowered.backtrackit D/zzz: scroll measuredHeight=1869, scrollY=568, alpha=0.568
2023-03-09 08:59:29.709 30661-30661/com.superpowered.backtrackit D/zzz: scroll measuredHeight=1869, scrollY=575, alpha=0.575
2023-03-09 08:59:29.726 30661-30661/com.superpowered.backtrackit D/zzz: scroll measuredHeight=1869, scrollY=583, alpha=0.583
2023-03-09 08:59:29.745 30661-30661/com.superpowered.backtrackit D/zzz: scroll measuredHeight=1869, scrollY=592, alpha=0.592
2023-03-09 08:59:29.829 30661-30661/com.superpowered.backtrackit D/zzz: scroll measuredHeight=1869, scrollY=607, alpha=0.607
2023-03-09 08:59:29.843 30661-30661/com.superpowered.backtrackit D/zzz: scroll measuredHeight=1869, scrollY=631, alpha=0.631
2023-03-09 08:59:29.859 30661-30661/com.superpowered.backtrackit D/zzz: scroll measuredHeight=1869, scrollY=636, alpha=0.636
2023-03-09 08:59:29.876 30661-30661/com.superpowered.backtrackit D/zzz: scroll measuredHeight=1869, scrollY=643, alpha=0.643
2023-03-09 08:59:29.893 30661-30661/com.superpowered.backtrackit D/zzz: scroll measuredHeight=1869, scrollY=649, alpha=0.649
2023-03-09 08:59:29.910 30661-30661/com.superpowered.backtrackit D/zzz: scroll measuredHeight=1869, scrollY=656, alpha=0.656
2023-03-09 08:59:29.926 30661-30661/com.superpowered.backtrackit D/zzz: scroll measuredHeight=1869, scrollY=663, alpha=0.663
2023-03-09 08:59:29.943 30661-30661/com.superpowered.backtrackit D/zzz: scroll measuredHeight=1869, scrollY=670, alpha=0.67
2023-03-09 08:59:29.960 30661-30661/com.superpowered.backtrackit D/zzz: scroll measuredHeight=1869, scrollY=676, alpha=0.676
2023-03-09 08:59:29.976 30661-30661/com.superpowered.backtrackit D/zzz: scroll measuredHeight=1869, scrollY=683, alpha=0.683
2023-03-09 08:59:29.993 30661-30661/com.superpowered.backtrackit D/zzz: scroll measuredHeight=1869, scrollY=689, alpha=0.689
2023-03-09 08:59:30.010 30661-30661/com.superpowered.backtrackit D/zzz: scroll measuredHeight=1869, scrollY=696, alpha=0.696
2023-03-09 08:59:30.027 30661-30661/com.superpowered.backtrackit D/zzz: scroll measuredHeight=1869, scrollY=703, alpha=0.703
2023-03-09 08:59:30.044 30661-30661/com.superpowered.backtrackit D/zzz: scroll measuredHeight=1869, scrollY=710, alpha=0.71
2023-03-09 08:59:30.060 30661-30661/com.superpowered.backtrackit D/zzz: scroll measuredHeight=1869, scrollY=718, alpha=0.718
2023-03-09 08:59:30.077 30661-30661/com.superpowered.backtrackit D/zzz: scroll measuredHeight=1869, scrollY=726, alpha=0.726
2023-03-09 08:59:30.093 30661-30661/com.superpowered.backtrackit D/zzz: scroll measuredHeight=1869, scrollY=734, alpha=0.734
2023-03-09 08:59:30.110 30661-30661/com.superpowered.backtrackit D/zzz: scroll measuredHeight=1869, scrollY=741, alpha=0.741
2023-03-09 08:59:30.127 30661-30661/com.superpowered.backtrackit D/zzz: scroll measuredHeight=1869, scrollY=749, alpha=0.749
2023-03-09 08:59:30.143 30661-30661/com.superpowered.backtrackit D/zzz: scroll measuredHeight=1869, scrollY=757, alpha=0.757
2023-03-09 08:59:30.162 30661-30661/com.superpowered.backtrackit D/zzz: scroll measuredHeight=1869, scrollY=764, alpha=0.764
2023-03-09 08:59:30.177 30661-30661/com.superpowered.backtrackit D/zzz: scroll measuredHeight=1869, scrollY=771, alpha=0.771
2023-03-09 08:59:30.193 30661-30661/com.superpowered.backtrackit D/zzz: scroll measuredHeight=1869, scrollY=779, alpha=0.779
2023-03-09 08:59:30.210 30661-30661/com.superpowered.backtrackit D/zzz: scroll measuredHeight=1869, scrollY=790, alpha=0.79
2023-03-09 08:59:30.227 30661-30661/com.superpowered.backtrackit D/zzz: scroll measuredHeight=1869, scrollY=800, alpha=0.8
2023-03-09 08:59:30.244 30661-30661/com.superpowered.backtrackit D/zzz: scroll measuredHeight=1869, scrollY=809, alpha=0.809
2023-03-09 08:59:30.260 30661-30661/com.superpowered.backtrackit D/zzz: scroll measuredHeight=1869, scrollY=818, alpha=0.818
2023-03-09 08:59:30.278 30661-30661/com.superpowered.backtrackit D/zzz: scroll measuredHeight=1869, scrollY=826, alpha=0.826
2023-03-09 08:59:30.294 30661-30661/com.superpowered.backtrackit D/zzz: scroll measuredHeight=1869, scrollY=835, alpha=0.835
2023-03-09 08:59:30.312 30661-30661/com.superpowered.backtrackit D/zzz: scroll measuredHeight=1869, scrollY=845, alpha=0.845
2023-03-09 08:59:30.327 30661-30661/com.superpowered.backtrackit D/zzz: scroll measuredHeight=1869, scrollY=856, alpha=0.856
2023-03-09 08:59:30.344 30661-30661/com.superpowered.backtrackit D/zzz: scroll measuredHeight=1869, scrollY=868, alpha=0.868
2023-03-09 08:59:30.360 30661-30661/com.superpowered.backtrackit D/zzz: scroll measuredHeight=1869, scrollY=879, alpha=0.879
2023-03-09 08:59:30.377 30661-30661/com.superpowered.backtrackit D/zzz: scroll measuredHeight=1869, scrollY=889, alpha=0.889
2023-03-09 08:59:30.394 30661-30661/com.superpowered.backtrackit D/zzz: scroll measuredHeight=1869, scrollY=900, alpha=0.9
2023-03-09 08:59:30.411 30661-30661/com.superpowered.backtrackit D/zzz: scroll measuredHeight=1869, scrollY=912, alpha=0.912
2023-03-09 08:59:30.428 30661-30661/com.superpowered.backtrackit D/zzz: scroll measuredHeight=1869, scrollY=924, alpha=0.924
2023-03-09 08:59:30.444 30661-30661/com.superpowered.backtrackit D/zzz: scroll measuredHeight=1869, scrollY=935, alpha=0.935
2023-03-09 08:59:30.460 30661-30661/com.superpowered.backtrackit D/zzz: scroll measuredHeight=1869, scrollY=947, alpha=0.947
2023-03-09 08:59:30.479 30661-30661/com.superpowered.backtrackit D/zzz: scroll measuredHeight=1869, scrollY=956, alpha=0.956
2023-03-09 08:59:30.495 30661-30661/com.superpowered.backtrackit D/zzz: scroll measuredHeight=1869, scrollY=967, alpha=0.967
2023-03-09 08:59:30.511 30661-30661/com.superpowered.backtrackit D/zzz: scroll measuredHeight=1869, scrollY=977, alpha=0.977
2023-03-09 08:59:30.528 30661-30661/com.superpowered.backtrackit D/zzz: scroll measuredHeight=1869, scrollY=988, alpha=0.988
2023-03-09 08:59:30.545 30661-30661/com.superpowered.backtrackit D/zzz: scroll measuredHeight=1869, scrollY=1000, alpha=1.0
2023-03-09 08:59:30.562 30661-30661/com.superpowered.backtrackit D/zzz: scroll measuredHeight=1869, scrollY=1010, alpha=1.0
2023-03-09 08:59:30.578 30661-30661/com.superpowered.backtrackit D/zzz: scroll measuredHeight=1869, scrollY=1019, alpha=1.0
2023-03-09 08:59:30.595 30661-30661/com.superpowered.backtrackit D/zzz: scroll measuredHeight=1869, scrollY=1028, alpha=1.0
2023-03-09 08:59:30.611 30661-30661/com.superpowered.backtrackit D/zzz: scroll measuredHeight=1869, scrollY=1036, alpha=1.0
2023-03-09 08:59:30.628 30661-30661/com.superpowered.backtrackit D/zzz: scroll measuredHeight=1869, scrollY=1045, alpha=1.0
2023-03-09 08:59:30.644 30661-30661/com.superpowered.backtrackit D/zzz: scroll measuredHeight=1869, scrollY=1054, alpha=1.0
2023-03-09 08:59:30.661 30661-30661/com.superpowered.backtrackit D/zzz: scroll measuredHeight=1869, scrollY=1062, alpha=1.0
…
2023-03-09 08:59:32.765 30661-30661/com.superpowered.backtrackit D/zzz: scroll measuredHeight=1869, scrollY=1563, alpha=1.0
2023-03-09 08:59:32.782 30661-30661/com.superpowered.backtrackit D/zzz: scroll measuredHeight=1869, scrollY=1571, alpha=1.0
2023-03-09 08:59:32.798 30661-30661/com.superpowered.backtrackit D/zzz: scroll measuredHeight=1869, scrollY=1579, alpha=1.0
2023-03-09 08:59:32.815 30661-30661/com.superpowered.backtrackit D/zzz: scroll measuredHeight=1869, scrollY=1587, alpha=1.0
2023-03-09 08:59:32.831 30661-30661/com.superpowered.backtrackit D/zzz: scroll measuredHeight=1869, scrollY=1594, alpha=1.0
2023-03-09 08:59:32.870 30661-30661/com.superpowered.backtrackit D/zzz: scroll measuredHeight=1869, scrollY=1601, alpha=1.0
2023-03-09 08:59:32.878 30661-30661/com.superpowered.backtrackit D/zzz: scroll measuredHeight=1869, scrollY=1609, alpha=1.0
2023-03-09 08:59:32.886 30661-30661/com.superpowered.backtrackit D/zzz: scroll measuredHeight=1869, scrollY=958, alpha=0.958 <——— Here
2023-03-09 08:59:32.898 30661-30661/com.superpowered.backtrackit D/zzz: scroll measuredHeight=1869, scrollY=964, alpha=0.964
2023-03-09 08:59:32.915 30661-30661/com.superpowered.backtrackit D/zzz: scroll measuredHeight=1869, scrollY=971, alpha=0.971
2023-03-09 08:59:32.932 30661-30661/com.superpowered.backtrackit D/zzz: scroll measuredHeight=1869, scrollY=977, alpha=0.977
2023-03-09 08:59:32.948 30661-30661/com.superpowered.backtrackit D/zzz: scroll measuredHeight=1869, scrollY=983, alpha=0.983
2023-03-09 08:59:32.965 30661-30661/com.superpowered.backtrackit D/zzz: scroll measuredHeight=1869, scrollY=990, alpha=0.99
2023-03-09 08:59:32.982 30661-30661/com.superpowered.backtrackit D/zzz: scroll measuredHeight=1869, scrollY=995, alpha=0.995
2023-03-09 08:59:32.998 30661-30661/com.superpowered.backtrackit D/zzz: scroll measuredHeight=1869, scrollY=1001, alpha=1.0
2023-03-09 08:59:33.015 30661-30661/com.superpowered.backtrackit D/zzz: scroll measuredHeight=1869, scrollY=1006, alpha=1.0
2023-03-09 08:59:33.032 30661-30661/com.superpowered.backtrackit D/zzz: scroll measuredHeight=1869, scrollY=1011, alpha=1.0
2023-03-09 08:59:33.049 30661-30661/com.superpowered.backtrackit D/zzz: scroll measuredHeight=1869, scrollY=1017, alpha=1.0
2023-03-09 08:59:33.065 30661-30661/com.superpowered.backtrackit D/zzz: scroll measuredHeight=1869, scrollY=1022, alpha=1.0
2023-03-09 08:59:33.082 30661-30661/com.superpowered.backtrackit D/zzz: scroll measuredHeight=1869, scrollY=1026, alpha=1.0
2023-03-09 08:59:33.099 30661-30661/com.superpowered.backtrackit D/zzz: scroll measuredHeight=1869, scrollY=1033, alpha=1.0
2023-03-09 08:59:33.115 30661-30661/com.superpowered.backtrackit D/zzz: scroll measuredHeight=1869, scrollY=1039, alpha=1.0
```

Is there a better solution than using `computeVerticalScrollOffset`? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

How many items you are passing to adapter? If the number is large enough you could perform smooth animation effect depending on which item is going to be displayed.

I guess you use `LinearLayoutManager`, so we can get last fully visible item, and later calculate percentage for alpha:

```
((LinearLayoutManager) recyclerView.getLayoutManager()).findLastVisibleItemPosition()
```